# Check if data exist in Firebase database with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on web project with Angular connected with Firebase console and I used this function defined in my service class to verify if the value exists in the database before saving, When I call this function in my component I usually get **undefined value**.

This is my service function :

```
  ifExist(category : CategoryType){
    firebase.database().ref("/categories/").child("categories").orderByChild("category_name").equalTo(category.category_name)
.once( "value" , snapshot => {
  if (snapshot.exists()){
    const userData = snapshot.val();
    console.log("exists!", userData);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});  
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: So did the answer work for you?

Comment: Why did you accept it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Your `return false` runs before your `if (snapshot.exists()){` is called, so you'll always return false.

The solution is to return a promise:

```
ifExist(category: CategoryType) {
  return firebase.database().ref("/categories/").child("categories")
    .orderByChild("category_name").equalTo(category.category_name)
    .once("value", snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const userData = snapshot.val();
        console.log("exists!", userData);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
}
```

And the use that when calling the function, either with:

```
ifExist(yourCategoryType).then((result) => {
  console.log("ifExist returned "+result);
});
```

Or with more modern `async` / `await`:

```
const result = await ifExist(yourCategoryType)
console.log("ifExist returned "+result);
```

Also see:

- [orderByChild not working in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893866/orderbychild-not-working-in-firebase/33897213#33897213)
- [asynchronous callback returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677977/asynchronous-callback-returns-null/25684264#25684264)
- [Wait until asynchronous operation (firebase) call is done before page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832656/wait-until-asynchronous-operation-firebase-call-is-done-before-page-loads/27840554#27840554)
- [Asynchronous Firebase query to response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158537/asynchronous-firebase-query-to-response)
- and probably many more from these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+asynchronous)

Comment: hello @Frank sorry but it's not working I usually get null as result in my component